# Как составить регулярное выражение grep для извлечения слова из строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, grep

Есть файл со строками вида:

```
</div><div class="yt-lockup-content"><a href="/watch?v=X5hMBxYqq5c" class="...
</div><div class="yt-lockup-content"><a href="/watch?v=6QpaQbxyw3Q" class="...
```

Как составить регулярное выражение в grep, чтобы вытащить оттуда все слова типа "/watch?v=..." (без кавычек)? Все испробованные мной варианты (с ключом -w в частности) возвращали строки, содержащие данные слова, а не сами слова.

В результате надо получить файл вида:

```
/watch?v=X5hMBxYqq5c
/watch?v=6QpaQbxyw3Q
...
```

Comment: `-o` судя по всему должен делать то что требуется

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что надо. В следующий раз буду внимательнее читать маны.

Answer (score 1):

Работает следующий вариант:

```
grep -o "/watch?v=..........." inp.txt > output.txt
```